# Join results in 3 tables to my existing query containing 2 tables

Tags: sql

Hopefully someone can show me how to complete my sql.  I'll start by showing you my existing query:

```
Select a.ID, a.NAME,
  CASE When b.SOURCE = Value1 then 'Rename1'
   When b.SOURCE = Value2 then 'Rename2'
   When b.SOURCE = etc. ....
END,
b.TARGET, b.COMPARE
FROM Table'a', Table'b'
WHERE b.SOURCE in(Value1, Value2, Value...etc)
AND (a.ID = b.ID_1 or a.ID = b.ID_2)
```

Now my issue is my client wants to look up 3 different tables (each table contains primary key = a.ID) and return the values from only the column values that are referenced in the Case Statement above.
I assume I would need to do a join but not sure how to go about it.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Puckhog

Answer (score 0):

Following is the sample query:

```
Select T1.column,T2.Column,T3.Column
From Table1 T1  
Join Table2 T2 
on T1.MatchingColumn=T2.MatchingColumn
Join Table3 T3
on T2.MatchingColumn=T3.MatchingColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this?

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, a.NAME, c.SOMETHING
FROM
    a
JOIN
   b 
ON a.ID = b.ID
JOIN 
   c
ON a.ID = c.ID
   WHERE [conditions]
```